Why do st_union and dplyr::summarise produce different results, with summarise giving me the object I want?
I have a file with 2013 geographical boundaries for NZ. The file looks like:

and the file overview is 
I used to work with the rgdal and rgeos packages, and am now updating the code so that it works with the sf package instead. And I am confused with how to merge polygons together, without creating a file that plots only the outer boundaries.
I can't work out why st_union is behaving unexpectedly (to me).
If I use dplyr I get the expected result:
 NZUAsDissolved <- NZAreasMerged %>%
   group_by(TA2013_label) %>%
   summarise() %>%
   ungroup()

 plot(NZUAsDissolved)


with the expected number of Territorial Authorities:

The suggestion for using dplyr was from a seemingly similar question.
But if I use
 NZUAsDissolved <- st_union(NZAreasMerged, by = "TA2013_label")

I get a different object


I only get the overall outline of New Zealand

What am I missing with the sf package? I am also loading the tmap and sp packages
Edited for what I was doing before. First I would create a data frame using gUnaryUnion to merge the multiple area units into their relevant territorial authority, e.g. "Far North District" contains multiple area units (Awanui, Karikari Peninsular-Maungataniwha, Taipa-Bay-Mangonui, Herekino,...) which meant that the 1,888 area units were merged into 67 territorial authorities. Then I would use SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to create the data frame I needed. I do need the Area Units later, in combination with the Territorial Authorities, hence the use of a GIS file that is at the Area Unit level of disaggregation.

Firstly, I don't know what version of sf you are using but by doesn't work like that for me (X is a column in my data):
> u = st_union(nc, by="X")
Error in s2::s2_union_agg(x, ...) : unused argument (by = "X")

It does get past this error if spherical geometry is turned off:
> sf_use_s2(FALSE)
Spherical geometry (s2) switched off
> u = st_union(nc, by="X")
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_union assumes that they are
planar

but experiment shows it ignores the by value.
st_union has a by_feature argument but that is not related to grouping features by a column, and can only be TRUE or FALSE:
by_feature: logical; if ‘TRUE’, union each feature if ‘y’ is missing or
          else each pair of features; if ‘FALSE’ return a single
          feature that is the geometric union of the set of features in
          ‘x’ if ‘y’ is missing, or else the unions of each of the
          elements of the Cartesian product of both sets

This is controlling if the union operation is done over all possible pairs of x and y (the Cartesian product), or only element-wise, that is return the union of x[1,] with y[1,], and x[2,] with y[2,] and so on.
In short, st_union does not do attribute-based dissolves.
This is with the latest version from CRAN, Version: 1.0-16.

Thanks, I edited my question to show the commands I was using before. It looks like dplyr will meet my needs, as I will continue to require attribute-based dissolves (emphasising a smaller geography within a larger one, for example). There is nothing in the sf package that does this? sf 1.0-15.

It is using the sf package implicitly when you use summarise on an sf object. The grouping by attribute and unioning is done in the pipeline by sf functions.

as a comment on @Spacedman's  answer:  should your workflow call for dissolving smaller units by some attribute, and {dplyr} prove as too heavy a dependency (which is perfectly reasoneable! it is a beast) you can consider base R aggregate - see https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/aggregate.sf.html

There's also rmapshaper::ms_dissolve which might do something similar but different. It has a few options not in aggregate.
